# How to compare current time with time stored in the database in Android

Tags: java, android

How to compare current date with value stored in the database? Currently my code looks as follows:

```
final String dDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4)));
final String dTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(5)));
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
String currentDate = formatter1.format(calendar1.getTime());

Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");
String currentTime = formatter2.format(calendar2.getTime());
if(currentDate.compareTo(dDate)>=0) {
  if (currentDate.equals(currentDate)) {
    if (currentTime.compareTo(dTime) > 0) {
      myCheckBox.setChecked(true);
      myCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer fails for all dates in future where the day of month is less than the current month's date. For e.g. It reports today 19/2/2015 is greater than 10/5/2015, 1/9/2020 etc. Comparing dates as string is just plain bad!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is working. Check out

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy h:mm");
String currentDate = formatter1.format(calendar1.getTime());

final String dateString = cursor.getString(4);
final String timeString = cursor.getString(5);
String datadb =dateString+" "+timeString;

//  Toast.makeText(context,"databse date:-"+datadb+"Current Date :-"+currentDate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

if(currentDate.compareTo(datadb)>=0) {
    myCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    myCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare dates as strings reliably. You should first combine your date and time strings from the cursor into a single `Date` object and then compare it with the current timestamp.

Your code should look something like

```
final String dDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4)));
final String dTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(5)));

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy h:mm");
Date dbDateTime = formatter.parse(dDate + " " + dTime);

if(new Date().compareTo(dbDateTime) >= 0) {
    myCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    myCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Here, `SimpleDateFormat#parse()` gives us a `Date` object containing both the date and time units initialized from the combined string. It can then simply be compared with a `new Date()` object which returns system's current date and time.

Comment: Does the date and time strings coming from the cursor belong to the same day?